# how to get Rssi value in tossim smulator

Tags: tinyos

I am using TinyOS 2.1.0 under Xubuntos in my project. I want to get the
 RSSI values in my simulation using TOSSIM as simulator. I used the command
call CC2420Packet.getRssi(msg)
The component is successfully buit. But when I built it for the simulation
(make micaz sim), i get an error saying that the component CC2420PacketC not
found.e 
i used also :

```
 event message_t* Receive.receive(message_t* pck,unit_8 len){
```

unit_8 Rssi_value=pck->metadata[1];

```
     dbg(DBG_USR2, "Receive signal strength as %d\n"


 (int)Rssi_value);
```

but i get allways 0 value for Rssi

Comment: RSSI is a value provided by the radio chip that indicates strength of the received radio signal. It just can't be obtained in a simulation when you don't use any real radio chip. You need to work on a real hardware. The `CC2420PacketC` component isn't available, because it's a chip-specific component. When you compile the application for simulations, the CC2420 radio chip driver is substituted with some mock chip-independent components.

Comment: i am working to localize sensor but by simulation tossim tinyos, maral if there any way i can simulate Rssi value, or if there is some other simulator that provides Rssi value and work with tinyos please let me knwo

Answer (score 0):

From what I learned from the forums(https://www.millennium.berkeley.edu/pipermail/tinyos-help/2007-July/026348.html) TOSSIM always sends at 0dbm and doesn't give dynamic change in the signal strength. Remember simulators have the limitations and Tossim assumes everything runs smoothly. But if you are interested in estimating quality you should consider some other parameter such as gain which can be programmed using the TOSSIM.